# How to remove 'With Live Tile' text from app store in windows phone?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I have uploaded an app in windows phone store.But it is showing 'With Live Tile' under app name.How to remove the 'With Live Tile' from windows phone app store.I am using pin,unpin API in my code.Is this is the root cause?

Answer (score 2):

> I am using pin,unpin API in my code.Is this is the root cause?

Yes that's the root cause. When you ever use/create tiles, actually a flag is being set if you ever created/used tiles within the application. If so, 'with Live Tile' tag is added to your app in the Store.

With a question like this, it's a better question, for what reason actually you want to remove the 'with Live Tile' tag, if you are already using tiles?